# JUnit test for Spring controller. Expected "200", but was "404"

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I am trying to test my Spring MVC controller with JUnit and I get this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
```

I guess my JUnit setup for controller tests isn't working like it should, but I really can't point out where the mistake is. I've read so many tutorials about this that it's getting frustrating.

This is simplyfied version of my LoginController class, but it will be enough

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
private DAO dao;

@RequestMapping(value = "username", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String GetUsername(Model model){

model.addAttribute("username", dao.getUsername());                  

    return "login"; //login.jsp 
}
```

And this is JUnit class which is testing that controller:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/Spring-Context.xml")
public class LoginControllerTest {

@Mock
private DAO dao;

@InjectMocks
LoginController controller;

private MockMvc mockMvc;


@Before
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(get("username")).andExpect(status().isOk());        
}
}
```

And I get "404". Same thing if I test example "forwardedUrl("/PATH/login.jsp")" the result is null.

My Spring-Context.xml has

> mvc:annotation-driven />

My console error is:
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [username] in DispatcherServlet with name ''

I don't really get that, because after all my application is working like it should so there is no problems with my mappings.

Comment: Try using `mockMvc.perform(get("/username")).andExpect(status().isOk()); ` and let me know

Comment: It will change the status of the test from failure to error. "Request processing failed; nested exception is NullPointerException".

Comment: If you're using somekind of IDE to develop your code and tests, then odds are, that your IDE has built in debugger. It is really helpful to execute your code in debugger and put a breakpoint before the line that throws NullPPointerException. Then you may see, which is the offending variable that is unexpectedly null. After that you may mock this variable to be something expected.

Comment: @TomJoad, did you find a solution to your problem? I'm facing something similar.